# Extending wp JavaScript base class to make a post request to a custom REST endpoint

Tags: ajax, javascript, rest-api, wp-api, endpoints

I've defined a REST endpoint `/my-plugin/v1/post-read` to show whether a post has been read or not, per-user. In PHP, my plugin keeps track of this depending on page views while logged in.

I'm now trying to add a front-end AJAX control to let users manually set a post as "unread" or "read". I've read that the WordPress REST API comes with a JavaScript library for interacting with it, and this is bundled with WordPress too. [According to the documentation](https://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/), this also handles authentication and noncing transparently, and one must simply extend a base class:

> For developers using the built-in Javascript API, this is handled
>   automatically for you. This is the recommended way to use the API for
>   plugins and themes. Custom data models can extend `wp.api.models.Base`
>   to ensure this is sent correctly for any custom requests.

I'd like to use this so I don't have to deal with nonces. I've found [an example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/267437/138112) how to use the library with the built-in post model, but I want to extend this for my custom endpoint.

I want to know whether it's appropriate to use and extend this library for sending `POST` requests, and if so, how I extend `wp.api.models.Base` to support this simple endpoint. All the examples I've found are for built-in objects like `post`, `taxonomy`, etc.